# I need with perfecting a project for beginners in terms of writing to a file

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to make sure the input the user uses is all letters.I tried the .alpha method but since this is a file, a "." will be included returning it false. I also tried using "quit" sentinel value to exit the program but that isn't working. It keeps saying break is outside the loop. I also want the user to keep inputting if the file is not found error is raised.
The Assignment[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCxTK.png)

```
def main():
 fileName = inputTxt()
 FiletoReadFrom = openingFile(fileName)
 counter = 0
 for line in FiletoReadFrom:
        outputFile = open("output.txt", "a+")
        counter = counter + 1
        outputFile.write("/* {} */ {}\n".format(counter, line.strip()))
 if counter == 0:
     print("This is an empty file")
 else:
     print("The file has been made")
     FiletoReadFrom.close()
     outputFile.close()
 
 
def inputTxt():
    flag = True
    while flag == True:
        FileName= input("Please Enter the Name of the File, or type quit to exit ")
        if FileName == quit:
            flag == False
            break
            print("goodbye")
        else:
            return FileName
    
     
def openingFile(filetoReadFrom):
 try:
    a = open(filetoReadFrom, 'r')
    return a
 except FileNotFoundError:
       print("This File was not Found", "Enter again or type quit to exit")
 

main()
```

Comment: Clean your question first, read the help on Markdown syntax

Comment: You are supposed to provide code formatted as code (I have done it for you this time). Beware: indentation matters in Python... And you should add the textual description of the assignment in the question itself, images are not necessarily welcome on SO. Finally you should say what is working what does not work (with a full description of input, expected output and actual output or error messages), and what you could not implement. When everything works, you should better ask the question on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get an extensive review and coding advices.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Note that Stack Overflow is not a coding service. In particular, if you have a specific problem or question then describe it properly; asking others to review and check your code is too broad and not a good question.

Comment: @rioV8 thank you, this was my first post and didn't quite understand it.

Comment: @SergeBallesta this was my first post and just copied and pasted from my idle. I will make sure I do all that next time.

Answer (score 0):

There are different questions here, which is frowned upon on this site. Please never do that again.

1. the *quit* and *break* problem:

   It is just a typo. As you forgot quoting `'quit'`, Python sees it at an undeclared variable which gives a syntax error. Fix:

   ```
    ...
    while flag == True:
        FileName= input("Please Enter the Name of the File, or type quit to exit ")
        if FileName == 'quit':
            flag == False
            break
            ...
   ```

   But it is still wrong, because break will only exit from the loop and `inputTxt` will return `None` which is not what you expect. Calling `sys.exit()` could be better here.
2. Test for letters and not numbers:

   You must choose a white list (only alphas and dot) or black list (no numbers) way. In idiomatic Python it could be:

   ```
    if all((x.isalpha() or x == '.') for x in FileName):  # white list
        # process error condition

    if any(x.isdigit() for x in FileName):                # black list
        # process error condition
   ```

   You could also use the `re` module which is great at controlling that a string respect a given pattern...
3. keep asking until a valid file is given:

   You should use a loop:

   ```
    def main():
        while True:
            fileName = inputTxt()
            FiletoReadFrom = openingFile(fileName)
            if FileToReadFrom is not None:  # openingFile returns None when file does not exist
                break
   ```

   But IMHO, you should remove the `openingFile` function and directly use (and test) `open` in main

Comment: This may not solve all the problems. But it should be enough to go one step further. If you still have problems, feel free to ask a new question with a reference to this one is it is relevant. But make sure to follow [ask] requirements: enough in the question itself to have it understandable, one single question, and a [mcve] with just enough (formatted) code to reproduce the problem, along with the input, expected output and actual output or the full error stacktrace if an exception is raised.

Comment: I had to use two def functions. One to get the input and the other either to open the file or write to it. I’ve spent hours trying to finish this assignment. I’ve been reading through my book, looking on YouTube, and google as well but still find myself stuck.